# Modifying picturebox on click [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an array of pictureboxes and they all have the same onclick method. The method is supposed to edit the `picturebox`. 
My code looks like this

```
box.Click += new System.EventHandler(boxClick);   
private void boxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        sender.Image = brush.CurrentImage;        
}
```

Not very complex, but for some reason the IDE is telling me that `object` is not containing a definition for Image.
But sender definitely has a Image property (I can even see it when debugging...)

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure it's possible to change a control's property on click...
Thanks

Comment: Where is Image being declared at is it in scope or out of scope..? also looks like you would need some Casting to get at what you want if I am not mistaken.. ((Sender)Image bla bla bla.. just first glance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. One of the Websites there most Webdevelopers think "damn, why this was not my idea". You will love it here ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

Right, `object` has no property `.Image`

#### Sample

You have to cast the `sender` to `PictureBox` like this

```
private void boxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as PictureBox).Image = brush.CurrentImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

sender is an object, which does not have the property Image.

You have to cast the object sender to a PictureBox, and then you can access its Image property.

```
private void boxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as PictureBox).Image = brush.CurrentImage;
}
```